# Where did Silverman used the condition $ j(E)∈\Bbb F_q (q＝p^2)$?

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$.
Then, according to Silverman's book ' the arithmetic of elliptic curves', $E$ is supersingular(dual of $p^r$-Frobenius is purely inseparable for all $r≧1$) if only if $[p]$ is purely inseparable and $j(E)∈$$\Bbb F_q $, where $q＝p^2$.

But is  $j(E)∈$$\Bbb F_q $$(q＝p^2)$ needed?

In the proof of showing $[p]$ is super singular and $j(E)∈$$\Bbb F_q $$(q＝p^2)$⇨ $E$ is super singular,
It seems we do not used the condition $j(E)∈$$\Bbb F_q $$(q＝p^2)$.

(I may have overlooked the process using $j(E)∈$$\Bbb F_q $$(q＝p^2)$)

In the showing process ' $[p]$ is super singular and $j(E)∈$$\Bbb F_q $$(q＝p^2)$⇨ $E$ is super singular' , where did he used the condition
$ j(E)∈$$\Bbb F_q $$(q＝p^2)$?

Comment: Apparently you do not understand the theorem from Silverman's book, since it directly tells you that the example you're asking for does not exist.

Comment: Thank you, my question's intention was completely misunderstood in the previous question. I modified.

Comment: Silverman is a bit unclear but we don't need the $j(E)\in F_{p^2}$ condition, instead we want to prove that $j(E)\in F_{p^2}$ when $E$ is supersingular.

Comment: @thank you. Maybe my question was solved. Is it difficult to prove $j(E)∈$$\Bbb F_q $ from $[p]$ is purely inseparable? (Silverman's book proves $j(E)∈$$\Bbb F_q $ from 'Dual of $p^r$-Frobenius is purely inseparable'.